# Package .exe application to run on a Mac

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, package-management

I have an application in the windows .exe format. It also uses a bunch of other dlls etc.

I want to hand it over to someone non technical who uses a mac and have him able to use the application.

Since the user is non technical and doesnt want to go through all the steps of installing a full vm with windows, what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your client/friend essentially has three options.

1. Install Windows to a partition via Bootcamp (or a similar solution).
2. Install Windows via a virtual machine.
3. Use a Windows Emulator.

Now, since you have said that installing Windows via a VM would be a bit beyond them, that pretty much eliminates options 1. and 2.  That leaves your friend with needing to use a Windows Emulator.

You could have your client/friend use...

- [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/). This would probably be the most robust emulator, but the most complicated to set up.  As has been pointed out, you may have difficulty finding a pre-compiled Wine build for Mac OSX, so feel free to [use one of these](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/wine/).  As per [this page](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX), there aren't many pre-compiled builds (and no official) for Mac OSX out there.
- [Winebottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/).  It's BETA, it uses WINE, but it is going to be a little friendlier.  Of course, this doesn't mean it won't be buggy.
- purchase [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/).  It's a commercial product, so it is going to be polished, easy to setup and use, and user friendly.  That's why it's not free.

Of course, you could find your own Windows Emulator, but this is the direction you are going to have to go in, regardless.

Comment: please add a link to http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/wine/ which is a osx build of wine Without Winebottler. Wine-only builds for OSX are kinda hard to come by.

Comment: by that I mean the link is hard to find.

Comment: @Hawken edited.  Already had the link to Winebottler there, but I can see where the individual might not dig through to find the Wine build without Winebottler.

Comment: yeah, I can't even remember where I found the link! So I keep it bookmarked. I guess if you run the site its easy to think, "well its right here can't they see it?"

Comment: **Wine is not an emulator**.

Comment: @hello71  Excellent.  You can read.  But for the purposes of this answer, in the context of a situation such as this, incorrectly calling it an emulator will suffice.